# Make Hidden child's relation /Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, relation, belongs-to

Model structure:

- `AccessoryGroup` (hasMany: `accessories`)
- `Accessory` (belongsTo: `accessory_group`)

Get all *accessory groups* with *accessories* (with `accesory_group`)

In `accessories` I needed `accessory_group` relation, to create some custom attribute (appends)

But after usage I don't won't my Api to return relation from `accessories->accessory_group`

```
AccessoryGroup
            ::with([
                'accessories' => function ($query) {
                    $accessory = $query->getRelated();
                    // Can I somehow use this $accessory relation for my problem
                    // something like $accessory->makeHidden('accessory_group'); - not working
                },
                'accessories.accessory_group',
            ])
            ->get();
```

when i add `public $hidden = ['accesory_group'];` in **Accessory** model I get what i want, but then it's always hidden (always need to use makeVisible)

Comment: use eloquent resources.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I get is you don't want to return the relation in return to your API response. I'm not prefer to load the data from relation again if you have that in parent model so suggest you do that in controller part to build your business logic.

But specific to your current problem you can do like this

```
$accessoryGroups = AccessoryGroup::query()
                 ->with([
                     'accessories',
                     'accessories.accessory_group',
                 ])
                 ->get();

// do your work here

// unset the relationship after your work complete
$accessoryGroups->each(function($accessoryGroup) {
    $accessoryGroup->accessories->each(function($category) {
        $category->unsetRelation('accessory_group');
    });
});

// return api response
```